# Simple form remove associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I'm using simple_form and I would give user ability to quickly remove an associated record. (eg. "checking/uncheking")
How is it possibile with simple_form? Is there another gem to help with this?

Parent **has many** children

```
<%= simple_form_for @parent do |f| %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :childens do |p| %>
    <%= p.input :title, as: :boolean %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

**Rails 5.2**

Comment: I've used something like https://github.com/lou/multi-select/ before to add this behavior. You just need to add an AJAX method to the deselect/select callbacks to add/remove associations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need another gem for that. There are several things you need to do:

- Add `allow_destroy: true` to the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :children` in the parent model
- Add a `<%= p.input :_destroy, as: :boolean %>` to the nested form
- Whitelist the `_destroy` pseudo attribute in your controller by listing it in `children_attributes` in the `permit` call

Essentially this is a feature of Rails' `accepts_nested_attributes_for` - it sets up the `children_attributes` setter to not only create/update associated records but also delete them in the presence of `_destroy` in the passed hash.